# Bootstrap 3 .img-responsive images are not responsive inside fieldset in FireFox

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Firefox (tested on Win7 and Win8), with the code below - when a responsive image is inside of a `<fieldset>` it is no longer responsive.  This means that as my form resizes for the phone, the image will not shrink accordingly.

I can "work-around" the issue easily, so I don't need any help with that.  However, if you know of a way to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

The responsive image in the code below will not be responsive to browser size in FireFox (at least on Win7 and Win8) unless you remove the `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Fieldset Responsive Image Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='content' class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1'>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>I Am Legend</legend>
                        <img class='img-responsive' src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI5MDAiIGhlaWdodD0iNTAwIj48cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iOTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0iIzY2NiIvPjx0ZXh0IHRleHQtYW5jaG9yPSJtaWRkbGUiIHg9IjQ1MCIgeT0iMjUwIiBzdHlsZT0iZmlsbDojNDQ0O2ZvbnQtd2VpZ2h0OmJvbGQ7Zm9udC1zaXplOjU2cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6QXJpYWwsSGVsdmV0aWNhLHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7ZG9taW5hbnQtYmFzZWxpbmU6Y2VudHJhbCI+U2Vjb25kIHNsaWRlPC90ZXh0Pjwvc3ZnPg==" alt="img" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

All you need is `width:100%` somewhere that applies to the tag as shown by the various answers here.

Using col-xs-12:

```
<!-- adds float:left, which is usually not a problem -->
<img class='img-responsive col-xs-12' />
```

Or inline CSS:

```
<img class='img-responsive' style='width:100%;' />
```

Or, in your own CSS file, add an additional definition for .img-responsive

```
.img-responsive { 
    width:100%;
}
```

**THE ROOT OF THE PROBLEM**

This is a known FF bug that `<fieldset>` does not respect overflow rules:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=261037

A CSS "FIX" to fix the FireFox bug would be to make the `<fieldset>` `display:table-column`.  However, doing so, according to the following link, will cause the display of the fieldset to fail in Opera:

https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/789

So, just set your tag to 100% width as described in one of the solutions above.

Comment: Recently I have found that this fixes the bug of `img-responsive` being inside `inline-block` element

Comment: yes also worked for me (to fix a FF size issue in bootstrap v3.3.7)

Answer (score 56):

This looks like [a Bootstrap issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10690)...

Currently, here's a workaround : add `.col-xs-12` to your responsive image.

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/116378)

Comment: So, I wasn't wanting a work-around at the `<img>` level but at the `<fieldset>` level (as in the answer I made)...but it looks like this work-around is the best solution, so I'm giving the bounty to you.

Comment: In fact col-xs-12 adds an unwanted float on your img element. Just add .img-responsive { width:100%; } to your CSS

Answer (score 11):

Change .img-responsive inside bootstrap.css to the following:

```
.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

For some reason adding width: 100% to the mix makes img-responsive work.

Comment: Same problem in purecss can be fixed by this.

Comment: I had an image in a table and this worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

in FF use inline style i.e.

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto;" />
```

It rocks :)

Comment: Why not better add it to css? It works for me. Inline is ugly ;)

Answer (score 3):

In my case I only wanted the image to behave responsively at mobile scale
so I created a css style .myimgrsfix that only kicks in at mobile scale

```
.myimgrsfix {
    @media(max-width:767px){
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

and applied that to the image `<img class='img-responsive myimgrsfix' src='whatever.gif'>`

Answer (score 2):

just add .col-xs-12 to your responsive image. It's should work.

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Comment: You don't need `padding:0` to my knowledge because the image itself is going to be `width:100%`. You would only need `padding:0` on a `.col-xs-12` that wrapped the image so that he image would take up the full-width...but that's not what we are talking about here.

Comment: @KevinNelson you're right. no need to add padding:0. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a browser bug.

> ## 10690: Reported a bug in Firefox for responsive images (those with max-width: 100%) in table cells. No other browsers are affected. See
>
> https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=975632.

[Source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10690)

`.img-responsive` in `<fieldset>` have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Change the img-class responsive to:

```
.img-responsive, x:-moz-any-link {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer given by Abdul.

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Image</legend>
   <img src="..." class="img-responsive" width="100%" />
</fieldset>
```

It works properly in FF 29, Opera 12.17, Chromium 34 and in IE9. Yes, it's a weird set of browsers!

Answer (score 0):

I created this script to solve the problem of the class img-responsive bootstrap3, and in my case this solved!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($.browser.msie) {

        var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;

        var images = $(".img-responsive");

        images.each(function(){

            var img = $(this);
            $("<img/>")
            .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
            .load(function() {
                pic_real_width = this.width;  

                pic_stretch_width = $(img).width();  

                if(pic_stretch_width > pic_real_width)
                {
                    $(img).width(pic_real_width);
                }
            });         
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For my issue, I didn't want my images scaled to 100% when they weren't intended to be as large as the container.

For my xs container (<768px as .container), not having a fixed width drove the issue, so I put one back on to it (less the 15px col padding).

```
// Helps bootstrap 3.0 keep images constrained to container width when width isn't set a fixed value (below 768px), while avoiding all images at 100% width.
// NOTE: proper function relies on there being no inline styling on the element being given a defined width ( '.container'  )

function setWidth() {
    width_val = $( window ).width();
    if( width_val < 768 ) {
        $( '.container' ).width( width_val - 30 );
    } else {
        $( '.container' ).removeAttr( 'style' );
    }
}

setWidth();
$( window ).resize( setWidth );
```

Answer (score 0):

add condition only firefox in your custom css file.

```
/* only Firefox */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
   .img-responsive, .thumbnail>img, .thumbnail a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .carousel-inner>.item>a>img {
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```